# Passing as a param

Tags: php

I found this code, but I'm unsure what it does exactly.

```
public function attach(IElement $element,IVisitor $colorVis)
{
    $element->accept($colorVis);
    array_push($this->elements,$element);
}
```

What does IElement and IVisitor do? Why do they need to be specified there? Thanks!

Comment: This code is going to need some context for anyone to be likely to guess what exactly those parameters are for or what the code is intended for.

Answer (score 2):

[Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)

`$element` must be an object and of the class `IElement` and `$colorVis` must be an object and of the class `IVisitor` or a catchable fatal error will be thrown.

So this function definition is defining the types or classes that the arguments must be.

Also, the `I` prefix is commonly used to mean Interface, but it may not be the case.

Comment: So it's an object being passed, Thought so. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but you can tell that by: `$element->`

Comment: I just wrote a basic class and passed $element without IElement. The result is the same?? It still works. So why pass IElement at all?

Comment: If the function and code is expecting `IElement` then you force it to be `IElement` or a fatal error is thrown.